# Magento,M2E extension, Usage guide -  listing items on eBay.

Tags: magento, m2e

I am new to Magento and I just installed M2E Pro extension for my store, but I don't know how to see the listed items on eBay. I've completed the configuration of eBay account in M2E, now need help.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to have created all your Templates accordingly (Selling, General, Description and Synchronization).
Then you need to go to eBay->Manage Listings->Listings and Create a New Listing.
Here you'll set the templates that will affect this Listing, and some other configuration options.
Then you need to add products to the Listing.

After that is done, you can now "List" you items, which means that Magento will upload the products to your eBay account and configure each publication according to the Templates you chose for your listing.

On eBay, you'll then see you published items as usual.